# Unable to reset the radio-button value in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two radio buttons where NO is the deault. Once a user clicks on the YES option I am saving this value and trying to make YES as the checked radio button. But I am unable to edit the default value once user changes their option. Here is my code:

```
    <body ng-app="mainModule" class="">
<div ng-controller="AdminConfigController">
    <div class="aui-page-panel aui-page-focused aui-page-focused-small" id = "continueDiscovery">
        <div class ="aui-page-panel-inner">
            <section class="aui-page-panel-content" >
                <label>Use User Story template while creating JIRA issue for Product features?</label>
                <div ng-repeat="eval in getEvaluators()">
                    <label class="radio" >
                        <input type="radio" ng-model="cell.evaluator" ng-click ="setConfig(cell.evaluator)" name="evaluatorOptions" value="\{{eval.name}}">\{{eval.name}}
                    </label>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div>You picked: \{{cell.evaluator}}</div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Controller code:

```
angular.module('mainModule').controller('AdminConfigController', function($scope, $http){


    $scope.cell = function() {
        return $http.get('/getAdminConfig/').success(function(data){
            template = data[0].userTemplate;

        }).error(function(data){
            console.log('Error: ' + data)
        });
    };

    $scope.cell = {
        evaluator: "NO"
    };

    $scope.updateCell = function (option) {
        $scope.cell = {
            evaluator: option
        };

        console.log($scope.cell)
    }
    $scope.evaluators = [{
        name: "YES"
    }, {
        name: "NO"
    }];
    $scope.getEvaluators = function () {
        return $scope.evaluators;
    };

    $scope.setConfig = function (option) {
        console.log("Config Choice:" + option)

        updateCell(option)

        $scope.option = option
        console.log("Entry Choice"+ $scope.option)

        var data = {
            userTemplate : $scope.option
        }

        $http.delete('/resetConfig/').success(function(data){

        }).error(function(data){
            console.log('Error: ' + data)
        });

        $http.post('/setAdminConfig/' , data).success(function(data){
            console.log(data)
            /*$scope.productDiscoveryData = data;*/
        }).error(function(data){
            console.log('Error: ' + data)
        });

    };
});
```

So if you look at the controller code I need to change the default value

```
$scope.cell = {
            evaluator: "NO"
        };
```

to the option selected by the user.

Comment: You have a few errors in your code that should be causing errors in the console. Your first reference to "scope", needs to be $scope. Within your $scope.setConfig function, you are referencing updateCell, which would give you an undefined error, it needs to $scope.updateCell.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this code help you.

```js
function AdminConfigController ($scope){
  $scope.Message = 'Hello Hi !';
  
  $scope.getEvaluators = function () {
        $scope.evaluators = [{name: "YES"}, {name: "NO"}];      
        return $scope.evaluators;
  };
   
    $scope.cell = {
        evaluator: "NO"
    };

    $scope.updateCell = function (option) {
        $scope.cell = {
            evaluator: option
        };

        console.log($scope.cell)
    }
    
 
    $scope.setConfig = function (option) {    
        console.log("Config Choice:" + option)

        $scope.updateCell(option);

        $scope.option = option
        console.log("Entry Choice"+ $scope.option)

        var data = {
            userTemplate : $scope.option
        }

       

       

    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="" class="">
<div ng-controller="AdminConfigController"> {{Message}}
    <div class="aui-page-panel aui-page-focused aui-page-focused-small" id = "continueDiscovery">
        <div class ="aui-page-panel-inner">
            <section class="aui-page-panel-content" >
                <label>Use User Story template while creating JIRA issue for Product features?</label>
                <div ng-repeat="eval in getEvaluators()"> {{$scope.cell.evaluator}}
                    <label class="radio" >
                        <input type="radio"  name="evaluatorOptions" ng-model="cell.evaluator"  value={{eval.name}}>\{{eval.name}} 
                      
                    </label>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div>You picked: \{{cell.evaluator}}</div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```